# Can we append data to a Vector in FlatBuffer?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I am working on this project where we store the log details for each run.
We are planning to use Flatbuffers for the same
This is my flatbuffer schema

```
table logData
{
   Id:int;
   attemptId:int;
   line:string;
}

table log
{
   maxLimit: int;
   counter: int;
   job:[logData]; //Vector of Tables
}
```

Now for the first run we just add data to the table using the helper functions provided by the Auto-Generated files

```
logBuilder build(builder);
builder.add_maxLimit(10);
auto data = builder.CreateVector(some_vector)
builder.add_job(data);
```

Now for the second run we have new data so, **Is there any way to append more data to the vector job, whilst keeping the old data intact?**

Comment: flat buffers are designed to store and transmit data. They are not designed to hold dynamic data in memory. It will probably be easier to read out the log into a vector, add to it and safe a new flat buffer at the end